# How to gracefully reload gunicorn changing symlink under supervisor

Tags: python, gunicorn, symlink, supervisord

I'm trying to gracefully reload my gunicorn process that is under a supervisor. My app deploy just change the symlink to my application folder and I can't find a way to make gunicorn gracefully update to the new version.

At the moment, when not using a symlink I can simply use the `supervisorctl signal HUP <app-name>` and it update the folder gracefully with 0 downtime, but I can't find a way to do it using symlink.

I also tried to use the same command with symlink and it does change it workers, but it doesn't reload the version of my app with the new symlink and keep using the old one.
Also tried to use `supervisorctl signal USR2 <app-name>` but it just create new process and doesn't swap the workers with the new ones and when I try to use TERM, it kill all process.

I already found the rainbow-saddle project, but it's no longer supported since 2016.

Does anyone has a clue to how handle this?

Thanks!!